# Laravel get uri from route name

Tags: php, laravel-8

I’m using Laravel’s routing component outside of Laravel so I don’t have the route() helper function, or any other helper method like app(). Can I still make use of route names? If so how can I get the route uri from a name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to loop through the route collection and match from name.

```
foreach($router->getRoutes() as $route) {

    if($route->action['as'] === $name) {
        return $route->uri;
    }
}
```